# How to change the column type in table using Entity Framework core

Tags: entity-framework-core

Hi I created my database using Entity Framework core with code first approach. Now there is a change in the column type from int to varchar/string?  I can change the column from the database itself but my understanding is that it won't be a good idea and would create issues.  I searched through but I didn't get my answer on the net for Entity framework core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [EF Core migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) to update your db schema. The documentation is pretty good, so make sure to go through it.

However, this is a summary of how the process would be:

1. Make the change in your model (which by convention will be automatically detected. Alternatively, use the Fluent API in your DB Context `OnCreate` method or in your `EntityConfiguration`s).
2. Add a migration running the following CLI command : `dotnet ef migrations add SomeDescriptiveNameAboutWhatThisMigrationWillDo`.
3. A migration file with an `Up` and `Down` method will be automatically generated. The `Up` will be run when you apply the migration, and the `Down` if you ever decide to revert it . You could add changes to the automatically scaffolded migration file. Based on the code in the migration file, EF Core will then generate a SQL script and apply the changes to the DB.
4. Once you have added (and maybe edited) the migration file, you need to apply it to the DB. You do that by running `dotnet ef migrations update`.
5. EF Core tracks all applied migrations in a table in your DB called by default `__EFMigrationsHistory`

In your particular case of changing a column type, EF Core might try to drop the column and recreate it, *which will result in data loss*. If you wanna keep your data, I would recommend altering the migration script to actually split the process in two: first add a new column with the new type and a slightly different name, then write some custom SQL to migrate data from the old column to the new one, then delete the old column and finally rename the new column to the correct name. To be honest, I am not sure if there is some custom migration operation that will out of the box change the data type without data loss, there might be.

To double check if the migration will generate data loss or check if it will do what you expect it to do, you can generate the SQL script that will be used by running `dotnet ef migrations script <from migration> <to migration>`. After reviewing it, you can either copy/paste and run the script in your DB, or just run the command detailed in step 4 above.

Comment: In visual studio 2022, for me the 4th step was `dotnet ef database update`. All other commands worked like a charm

Comment: @gdogra That will run the migration without giving you a chance ton review what are the exact operations that will be performed in the database. Since that's a little risky, I prefer to generate the script, review it, and then manually run it in the db. On the other hand, Dotnet ef database update is fine for your localhost environment 

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your database schema to match your domain model with the [add-migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) command.
After changing the type of the property on your c# class from int to string, simply run

```
add-migration <SomeDescriptiveName>
```

After the creation of the migration files, you can apply them with the update-database command.

You can read more about migrations [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli).